# Problem with Kelvin Luck datepicker [Select Past Dates]

Tags: php, cakephp, datepicker

in my project I'm using this datepicker, I read how to put it into Cakephp here: http://bakery.cakephp.org/articles/agusti/2010/02/02/transparent-datepicker-with-jquery

When I change format to ymd (Ex: 2011-12-10), I can´t select past dates like in the example. http://www.kelvinluck.com/assets/jquery/datePicker/v2/demo/datePickerPastDate.html 
I can't understand how to make past dates selectable.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I found the answer, just need to edit this line:

```
this.startDate = null;
```

to:

```
this.startDate = '2000-01-01';
```

And edit this:

```
this.setStartDate(s.startDate);
```

to:

```
this.setStartDate('2000-01-01');
```